# java - insertiosSort - Don't understand

Tags: java, arrays, nested-loops, insertion-sort

I've recently learned insertionSort and I don't understand how does the linked code works...
If someone can please explain row by row I'd very appreaciate it.

Thansks for your time.

[The code:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8lwzw.png)

let's take for example this array: array={ 30,16,12,51,37,18,24,8,23,24}
I will try to demonstrait how my line of thought is and hopefully you would be able to correct my mistakes.

So, I know that at the start i=1, and than when "newest" is getting the value of a[i] which in this case is a[1]=16, now we go to the inner loop, the value of j is i-1 = 0, therefore j=0, and as long as j>=0 and a[j]=30 is greater than newest(in this case a[1]=16), a[j+1] = a[j] - ( from here on I don't undertand),
does a[j+1] = a[j] mean that instead of a[1]=16 now a[1] = 30? if so where does the 16 goes ? and how does we keep on going from there ?

Comment: Please [DO NOT USE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) images of code. Send the copied and formatted code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

the inner loop will continue for all elements greater then newest, once the inner loop is complete then a[j] means 16 (for the first iteration of the outer loop) will be moved. you can follow this, hope this will help you.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OGzPmgsI-pQ